# Who proposes blocks in Ethereum Casper the Friendly Ghost

Tags: proof-of-stake, casper

I am trying to understand how CTFG is supposed to work. The available online blogs provide a fairly high-level overview. What I have understood so far is that validators will bet on the blocks as they see and think are going to make the canonical chain. However, one thing I am struggling to understand who is going to propose a new block in CTFG? It is very clear in CFFG but not in any discussion on CTFG.

Any clarification or pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks.